# A strange growth speed equation

Tags: calculus, contest-math

This question has had me stumped for months, now... 
It is as quotes:

> The population of fish in a bay (measured in thousands of fish) at time $t$ is described by the function $p(t) = t^4 + t^2 + 500$, where $t$ is measured in weeks. How fast is the population increasing after 4 weeks?

Now the question had an answer sheet, claiming the correct answer to be

`"264,000 first per week".`

I can't, for the life of me, figure out how this answer was reached. How did an answer of "264,000" get reached by an equation like $p(t) = t^4 + t^2 + 500$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivative $p'(t)$ gives you the rate of change of the fish. Since $p(t)=t^4+t^2+500$, $p'(t)=4t^3+2t$.

Now, since the problem states that time is measured in weeks, plug in $t=4$ into the derivative to get the rate of change after $4$ weeks. You get $p'(4)=4*4^3+2*4=264$.

The problem also states that the fish is measured in thousands, which means that the rate of change of fish after $4$ weeks is $264000$ fish.